# Which is the correct MicroPython firmware for the board-esp32-s3-devkitc-1 to use with the WOKWI VS Code simulator?

Tags: visual-studio-code, esp32, simulator, micropython

I am trying to run WOKWI vscode simulator of board-esp32-s3-devkitc-1, i tried firmware downloaded from the following link https://micropython.org/download/ESP32_GENERIC_S3/ but its giving me the following error:
[image]

following are the project files:

diagram.json:

```
    "version": 1,
    "author": "Anonymous maker",
    "editor": "wokwi",
    "parts": [
        { "type": "board-esp32-s3-devkitc-1", "id": "esp", "top": 0, "left": 0, "attrs": {} },
        { "type": "wokwi-dht22", "id": "dht1", "top": -139.68, "left": 21.23, "attrs": {} }
    ],
    "connections": [
        ["esp:TX", "$serialMonitor:RX", "", []],
        ["esp:RX", "$serialMonitor:TX", "", []],
        ["dht1:VCC", "esp:3V3.1", "red", ["v0"]],
        ["dht1:GND", "esp:GND.2", "black", ["v0"]],
        ["dht1:SDA", "esp:4", "green", ["v0"]]
    ],
    "dependencies": {}
}
```

wokwi.toml:

```
[wokwi]
version = 1
firmware = './new/ESP32_GENERIC_S3-SPIRAM_OCT-20230426-v1.20.0.bin'
elf = './new/ESP32_GENERIC_S3-SPIRAM_OCT-20230426-v1.20.0.elf'
```

main.py

```
import time
from machine import Pin
import dht

sensor = dht.DHT22(Pin(4))

while True:
    try:
        # Read data from the DHT22 sensor
        sensor.measure()
        temperature = sensor.temperature()
        humidity = sensor.humidity()

        # Print the readings
        print("Temperature: {:.2f}°C".format(temperature))
        print("Humidity: {:.2f}%".format(humidity))

    except OSError as e:
        print("Error reading data:", e)

    # Wait for a moment before taking the next reading
    time.sleep(2)
```

I believe the MicroPython firmware I'm currently using for the board-esp32-s3-devkitc-1 might not be the correct one. Could you assist me in finding the appropriate firmware that is compatible with the WOKWI board-esp32-s3-devkitc-1 simulator?